# Latex Table Question

Tags: support, mathjax

Here's a [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115280/create-a-table-with-latex) to a SE question-answer on building tables using Latex.  I copied the following bit of Latex code from the top-rated answer and when I pasted it in to an answer on Chemistry SE it didn't produce the expected part of the table.  Is Latex not fully supported on Chemistry SE, or did I make some kind of error?

\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{A data table.}
 \label{tbl:1}
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
   A & B \\
   C & D
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

EDIT: So if the {table} method doesn't work in MathJax, how, using the {align} method, could I rework the table MannishEarth created in his answer, but with the first row continuous (no columns in only the first row) with "123" centered within it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\begin{table}...\end{table}` would create a floating object, which is not really possible in a website anyways.

Since `\multicolumn{3}{c}{1 2 3}` is not permitted in arrays, [arrays inside arrays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50627/33413) is your only option.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{a b c}\\\hline
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & 8 & 9\\
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm going to play around with this.

Comment: @ron You are welcome, however, I would recommend avoiding them as often as possible, it is almost always coding pain, as it is easy to forget a parentheses/ closing argument... and then you are searching longer for the error than it took to post the answer :/

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
2 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 5 & 6
\end{array}$$

`\begin{array}` works (right click for mathjax source)

That being said, MathJax only supports a subset of LaTeX. It's not for general typesetting, so expect a lot of LaTeX features to be missing.

Comment: @MannishEarth  Thanks Mannish!  "expect a lot of LaTeX features to be missing"  Aha, I guess that explains it.  I did wind up using the "\begin{array}" method.  If I wanted the first row to be continuous (no columns in only the first row) with "123" centered within it, is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: @ron uh, I think so, but I forgot exactly how the LaTeX array syntax works.

Comment: The background is that MathJax focuses on math-mode LaTeX. The table environment is a text-mode macro and thus not in scope (it fits more naturally with markdown, I suppose). For a complete list of TeX macros supported by MathJax, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands

Comment: Thanks for the link Peter. The link on that page leading to Carol Fisher's treasure trove of MathJax illustrated commands was a good one too.   http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm

Comment: Be aware, that you will have to escape text in tables via `\text{...}`, otherwise it will be set as variables. Unfortunately on meta.se it does not say why the status is declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/260760